# The property "properties" is read-only

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a SQL Server with several databases and I have created an elastic pool. I wanted to add all the non elastic DB's to the elastic pool using bicep. Using the code below there are no changes with dry run.

```
param serverName string
param elasticPoolName string
param databaseNames array

resource server 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serverName
}

resource elasticPool 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools@2022-02-01-preview' existing = {
  parent: server
  name: elasticPoolName
}

resource db 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-02-01-preview' existing = [for dbName in databaseNames: {
  name: dbName
  parent: server
  properties: {
    elasticPoolId: elasticPool.id
  }
}]
```

In VS Code, I'm getting a warning on properties block.

> The property "properties" is read-only. Expressions cannot be assigned to read-only properties. If this is an inaccuracy in the documentation

Am I using any resources wrongly?

Comment: you are using the `existing` keyword on the databases resources. `existing` is only used to get a reference to an existing database not to update an existing resource.

Comment: got it, then is there any way to update the existing database. if we remove ```existing```  it will create a new Database.

Comment: have you try just updating ? it shouldnot create a new db if you re uysing same name / parent etc. it should just add the db to the pool specified ?

Comment: Are you looking for only bicep code? @AjithSelvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding the database into an existing elastic pool, you dont need to use the `existing` keyword instead include `elasticPoolId: elasticPool.id` directly under `properties` block of an existed database will forcely adds database into an elastic pool as shown below.

```bash
param serverName string = 'jahnaviser'
param elasticPoolName string = 'newpool'
param databaseNames string = 'newjdb' //My existed database

resource server 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serverName
}

resource elasticPool 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools@2022-02-01-preview' existing = {
  parent: server
  name: elasticPoolName
}
resource sqlDB 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  parent: server
  name: databaseNames
  location: location
  properties: {
    elasticPoolId: elasticPool.id
}   
}
```

*Note:* You can execute the same using `for` loop for multiple databases accordingly.

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When doing whatif, the result was showing as X no effect , so I thought It wont change anything, but thats the correct way to do.